# Is there a way to add two filter together as one filter in edge detection?

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, scipy.ndimage

When I do an edge detection, I normally first use a Gaussian filter:

```
 img_blur = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(img,2,truncate = 2.25)
```

Then a gradient filter:

```
Ix= scipy.ndimage.convolve(im, dx)
Iy = scipy.ndimage.convolve(im, dy)
```

Where dx and dy are the two filters in the horizontal and vertical directions.
Then I will compute for the edge:

```
edges = Ix**2 + Iy**2
```

My question is there a way to combine the gaussian filter and the gradient filter into one filter?
Let's call this filter f, can I do something like:

```
f= scipy.scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(img,2,truncate = 2.25) + scipy.ndimage.convolve(im, dx)
```

? I know this is not a legal expression, but is there a way to correctly implement this filter f or is there any other filter that has the same effect? I am doing horizontal and vertical filters separately, so f just needs to be one direction at a time. This filter need to go through another convolution to get the final result, which means it needs to go through another

```
result = scipy.ndimage.convolution(img,filter)
```

to get the final result.

Comment: `scipy.ndimage.convolve(im, dx)` returns a blurred image, which you could pass then to the horizontal filter doing `scipy.ndimage.convolve(scipy.ndimage.convolve(im, dx), dx)` but then when applying the vertical filter you will need to compute the gaussian filter again, unless you use a kernel that detects both vertical and horizontal gradients. But why do you want to combine them? it's a good idea the have each filter applied separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two successively applied filters can be combined into a single filter just by convolving their kernels together.

You could, therefore, combine the Gaussian with each of the gradient filters to make two combined Gaussian-gradient filters, but...

You do *not* want to do this, because a gradient filter is very fast + simple, while a Gaussian filter is a more complex operation.  A combined Gaussian-gradient filter is also a complex operation.  Applying the two (slow) combined filters would be **slower** that applying a single Gaussian filter followed by two gradients.

In fact, all of the filters we are talking about are *[separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter)*. The gradient filters operate only in one direction (horizontal or vertical), and the other filters (Gaussian and combination) are most efficiently implemented as *two* filter applications, one horizontal and one vertical.

So in combining the filters, if you were to take the care to implement your combined filters efficiently, then you would really trading 4 directional filter applications (Gaussian X, Gaussian Y, Gradient X, Gradient Y) for 4 *slower* directional filter applications (CombinedX X, CombinedX Y, CombinedY X, CombinedY Y).  These are slower, because you no longer have any of those quick+simple gradient passes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `convolve` filter uses result of previous one. To calculate value of convolve, you need blurred values of neighbors. When you apply 2 filter to 1 image, sometimes you can combine them. You apply 2 filter on 2 different images.

Theoretically you can find some implementations of second step in 1 step. In practical I don't saw something like that before. You can write yourself. For effective implementation you need to use more hardware oriented language (ex. C++) and use SIMD instructions for faster implementation.

Sembei in comments ask right questions. Why you want run in 1 filter? Maybe we can suggest other ways to solve your problem.